# Custom Font Not Displaying

Tags: html, css, fonts

Trying to define a custom font:

```
@font-face {
font-family: Helvetica Light; src:url('/font/Helvetica-Light.otf');
font-family: Helvetica Oblique; src:url('/font/Helvetica-BoldOblique.otf');
font-family: Helvetica Oblique; src:url('/font/Helvetica-LightOblique.otf');    
font-family: Helvetica Neue; src:url('/font/HelveticaNeueLTStd-ThEx.otf');
font-family: Helvetica Oblique; src:url('/font/Helvetica-Oblique.otf');
}
```

and I'm calling it:

```
h1 {
    font-family: Helvetica Neue;
}

h2 {
    font-family: Helvetica Oblique;
    font-weight:bold;

}

.input {
    font-family: Helvetica Oblique;
    font-weight: light;
}
```

But its not displaying, what am I doing wrong here? I did a bit of googling, from what I can see OTF should be supported within FF and IE?

Comment: Your should use `src:url('../font/Helvetica-BoldOblique.otf')` (notice the double dots) to refer to directorys one level down from the root folder if your css is in a separate folder.

Comment: Same as for font name, url also doesn't need `'` or `"`. See my answer for a working solution. I just tested with and without `'` and `"` and it works fine even without quotes. My answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17147597/1812633

Comment: This isn’t a real question unless you provide essential information, such as the origin of the font, the location of the font files relative to the HTML and CSS documents, and preferably a working URL for seeing online what really happens.

Answer (score 2):

One `font-face` can create only one custom font. `'` or `"` don't really matter. It will work anyway. But I would advice you to use them because not using them seems a bit unnatural to me.

#### EDIT: You should use `'` in `font-family` names and `url`s, like the first one

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Light';
    src:url('/font/Helvetica-Light.otf'); /* will work even without ' or " */
}                                         /* but still! use ' dont remove them */

@font-face {
    font-family: Helvetica Oblique;
    src:url('/font/Helvetica-BoldOblique.otf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Helvetica Oblique;
    src:url('/font/Helvetica-LightOblique.otf');
}    

@font-face {
    font-family: Helvetica Neue;
    src:url('/font/HelveticaNeueLTStd-ThEx.otf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Helvetica Oblique;
    src:url('/font/Helvetica-Oblique.otf');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to use inverted commas if a font-family consists of more than 1 word:

cf: `font-family: Helvetica;` and `font-family: "Helvetica Neue";`

Secondly - there are special web-font formats that are used in `@font-face` - they are: `.eot`, `.woff`, `.ttf` and `.svg`. You need to use some tool to generate these fonts for you.

Thirdly - not all the fonts that are out there are free to use in your web-project. [Helvetica](http://www.fonts.com/font/linotype/helvetica), for instance, costs some money.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147290/custom-font-not-displaying/17147343#17147343

Comment: `'` and `"` are not really required. Just tested 3 fonts and it works fine even without them. Although I was unable to make multiple custom fonts in a single `font-face` property.

Comment: @Sourabh, you are right that inverted commas are not obligatory, but they are preferable because they prevent you from [making various mistakes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family#Valid_family_names)

Comment: So **rule of thumb** is: Don't give your font a weird name. just use `A-Z`, `a-z`, `<spaces>`, `0-9` and nothing else.

Comment: What suits you may suit others :) My rule of thumb is to use the commas if the name contains spaces, probably it's some form of conservatism, I don't know ))

Comment: My rule of thumb is to use quotes for all real font names so they're easily distinguished from the font family keywords (serif etc).

Comment: @MrLister Even I do this. Not using `'` for custom names seems a bit weird.

Answer (score 1):

im using this code (all formats what u need for all browsers):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontName';
    src: url('FileName.eot');
    src: url('FileName.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('FileName.woff') format('woff'),
         url('FileName.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('FileName.svg#FontName') format('svg');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

and then i just call it :

```
.some-class {
     font-family: 'FontName';
}
```

for font converting use http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Answer (score 0):

Try including fonts with more than one word within inverted commas.

**For instance,**

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Helvetica Light"; src:url('/font/Helvetica-Light.otf');
font-family: "Helvetica Oblique"; src:url('/font/Helvetica-BoldOblique.otf');
font-family: "Helvetica Oblique"; src:url('/font/Helvetica-LightOblique.otf');    
font-family: "Helvetica Neue"; src:url('/font/HelveticaNeueLTStd-ThEx.otf');
font-family: "Helvetica Oblique"; src:url('/font/Helvetica-Oblique.otf');
}

h1 {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
}

h2 {
    font-family: "Helvetica Oblique";
    font-weight:bold;

}

.input {
    font-family: "Helvetica Oblique";
    font-weight: light;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS :
    h1 {
        font-family:'Helvetica Neue';
    }

```
h2 {
    font-family:'Helvetica Oblique';
    font-weight:bold;

}

.input {
    font-family:'Helvetica Oblique';
    font-weight: light;
}
```

Comment: Although using quotes is strongly recommended (and I'd use them even for fonts without spaces), it is not absolutely necessary unless in special cases, e.g. the font name contains tabs, or two spaces in a row. And it won't make a difference, since in the OP's case, the error lies elsewhere.